# Increase Width of slider Jssor

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I have just started using jssor slider.
I know there are many examples related to jssor slider, but I want a customized slider according to needs.

I have just created simple slider from scratch with jssor and I want to increase the width and height of slider.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: true};
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
                        <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="img/01.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="img/02.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for this code

```
 function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize,1200);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
```